# Using shared memory in Dynamic Parallelism CUDA

Tags: cuda, dynamic-parallelism

**Question 1:**
Do I have to specify the amount of dynamic shared memory to be allocated at the launch of parent kernel if shared memory is only used by child kernel.

**Question 2:**
The following is my child kernel and parent kernel

Parent kernel

```
__global__ void ColumnFractionalShift(DataIn DataInput,float* __restrict__ DeviceInput, float ShiftAmount, float* __restrict__ LightFieldDevice)
{
    cudaError_t status;
    float ImageShift = threadIdx.x*ShiftAmount;
    float ImageIntegerShift = nearbyintf(ImageShift);
    float Delay = ImageShift - ImageIntegerShift;
    int InputImageOffset = +DataInput.X*DataInput.Y*DataInput.U*(threadIdx.y) + DataInput.X*DataInput.Y*(threadIdx.x);
    dim3 dimBlock(32, 24);
    dim3 dimGrid(16, 14);
    //if (threadIdx.x > 5)
    {
        ConvolutionColumn << <dimGrid, dimBlock, ((sizeof(float)* 24 * 32 * 3)) >> >(DataInput, DeviceInput + InputImageOffset, Delay, LightFieldDevice + InputImageOffset);
    }
    status = cudaGetLastError();
    if (status != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("failed %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(status));
    }
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    if (threadIdx.x == 5)
    {
        printf("The values at beginig of %d  %d are %f\n", threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, *(LightFieldDevice + InputImageOffset));
    }
}
```

Child Kernel

```
__global__ void ConvolutionColumn(DataIn DataInput,float* __restrict__ DeviceInput, float Delay, float* __restrict__ DeviceResult)
{
    extern __shared__ float ConvolutionBlockLeft[];
    int BlockStart = blockDim.y*blockIdx.y*DataInput.V + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    //int BlockEnd = BlockStart+(blockDim.x*blockDim.y)-1;
    int PixelId = blockDim.x*threadIdx.y + threadIdx.x; //32 by 24 kernal
    int LoadPixelId = DataInput.V*threadIdx.y + threadIdx.x;
    int LoadLeft,LoadRght,LoadCentre;
    float KernalSum;
    float DelayPower = Delay;
    //load upper values
    if (blockIdx.y == 0)
    {
        LoadLeft = DataInput.V*(blockDim.y - threadIdx.y-1) + threadIdx.x;
    }
    else
    {
        LoadLeft =  LoadPixelId - (DataInput.V*blockDim.y);
    }
    *(ConvolutionBlockLeft + (threadIdx.y*blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x) = *(DeviceInput + BlockStart + LoadLeft);
    if (blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y >= DataInput.U)
    {
        LoadCentre = ((DataInput.U - 1)*DataInput.V) + (blockDim.x*blockIdx.x) + threadIdx.x - ((blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y) - DataInput.U)*DataInput.V;
    }
    else
    {
        LoadCentre = BlockStart+LoadPixelId;
    }
    *(ConvolutionBlockLeft + (blockDim.x*blockDim.y) + (threadIdx.y*blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x) = *(DeviceInput + LoadCentre);
    if (blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y + blockDim.y >= DataInput.U)
    {
        LoadRght = ((DataInput.U - 1)*DataInput.V) + (blockDim.x*blockIdx.x) + threadIdx.x - ((((blockIdx.y*blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y + blockDim.y) - DataInput.U)*DataInput.V);
    }
    else
    {
        LoadRght = BlockStart+LoadPixelId + (DataInput.V*blockDim.y);
    }
    //float tempfil, tempdata;
    //int t;
    *(ConvolutionBlockLeft + (2 * blockDim.x*blockDim.y) + (threadIdx.y*blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x) = *(DeviceInput + LoadRght);
    __syncthreads();
    float FilterSum = *(ConvolutionBlockLeft + ((blockDim.x*blockDim.y) + PixelId));
    for (int k = 1; k < DataInput.KernalNoOfFilters; k++)
    {
        KernalSum = 0;
        //printf("The value of filter size is %d\n", (DeviceFilterSize[k]));
        for (int l = -((*(DeviceFilterSize + k) - 1) / 2); l < ((*(DeviceFilterSize + k) + 1) / 2); l++)
        {
            //tempfil = *(DeviceFilterKernal + k*DataInput.KernalFilterLength + ((*(DeviceFilterSize + k) - 1) / 2) + l);
            //t = (blockDim.x*blockDim.y) + PixelId + (l*blockDim.x);
            //tempdata = *(ConvolutionBlockLeft + ((blockDim.x*blockDim.y) + PixelId - (l*blockDim.x)));
            KernalSum += *(DeviceFilterKernal + k*DataInput.KernalFilterLength + ((*(DeviceFilterSize + k) - 1) / 2) + l)**(ConvolutionBlockLeft + ((blockDim.x*blockDim.y) + PixelId - (l*blockDim.x)));
        }
        KernalSum *= DelayPower;
        DelayPower *= Delay;
        FilterSum += KernalSum;
    }
    if (blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y < DataInput.U)
    {
        *(DeviceResult + LoadPixelId + BlockStart) = FilterSum;
    }
}
```

Here child kernel alone works fine. However when its launched from another kernel, after parent kernel launch from host at `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` unspecified launch failure error is given(The error isn't printed from printf within the kernel).

The launch configuration of parent kernel is `<<<1,(17 17)>>>`. If only one thread from parent is allowed to launch the child grid then the code works fine. Is there a limit on how many grids that can be launched from one block?

Comment: The three word answer here is No and No. As I said in your last attempt to ask this question -- you need to provide an [MCVE] if you want an answer which explains the source of your problem. That means a short, comlete example code, plus how you are compiling the code and how and on what hardware you are running this. If you can't supply this you are extremely unlikely to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to specify the amount of dynamic shared memory to be allocated at the launch of parent kernel if shared memory is only used by child kernel.

No, you only specify dynamic shared memory allocation on the actual kernel invocations that will need/use it.  You do not have to take into account child kernel needs on parent kernel launches.

> Is there a limit on how many grids that can be launched from one block?

There isn't any such limit.  There is a [`cudaLimitDevRuntimePendingLaunchCount`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#configuration-options), but by default it is set to 2048, which would appear to exceed your request of 17*17 = 289, and furthermore you don't appear to be receiving this particular error.  (And this is a dynamic limit, so the simple fact that a parent kernel appears to be launching more than this limit does not guarantee that this limit/error will be hit. It depends on the actual dynamic launch behavior.)

If the question you'd like to ask is "why isn't this code working?", then you [should](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).